# node.js and socket.io - emit messages to client side are disappear if page reload

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, sockets, express

I am building a realtime chat web application with node.js and socket.io, the message can successfully append to the client side using jQuery after socket emit data from server. However everytime when user reload the page, message are all gone. I've also try .load and .html, still the same problem, is there an elegant way to solve this? Thanks.

`socket.on('message', function(data) {
        $('#messageArea').append('<div>' + data + '</div>');
    });`

Uncaught TypeError: messages.forEach is not a function

```
        if (localStorage.getItem('data') !== null) {
        var username = localStorage.getItem('username', data.username);
        var messages = localStorage.getItem('message', data.message);
        if (messages) {
            messages.forEach(function(username, message) {
                $('#chatArea').append('<div>' + username + ' : ' + message + '</div>');
            });
            console.log(typeof(messages)); // string
            console.log(typeof(message)); // obj
            console.log(messages); // some text input
        }
    }
```

Server-Side

```
     // Send Message From Server
  socket.on('send message', function(message, username, date) {
      io.sockets.emit('show message', message, username, date); });
```

Client-Side

```
        // Show Message
socket.on('show message', function(username, message, date) {

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

        if (message) {
            var messages = localStorage.getItem('message');
            messages += ';'
        }
        messages += message;
        localStorage.setItem('username', username);
        localStorage.setItem('message', messages) || '';
        localStorage.setItem('date', date);

        messages.split(';').each(function() {
            $('#chatArea').append('<div class="well well-sm">' + localStorage.getItem('username') + ' : ' + localStorage.getItem('message') + ' <span class="pull-right"><small id="date"> at ' + localStorage.getItem('date') + '</small></span></div>');
        });


    } else {
        $('#chatArea').append('<div>The Storage is not working in this browser</div>');
    } 
});
```

Comment: I'd go for [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: The messages are not persisted to any storage. If you like them to appear after a reload you have to store them in a storage like sessionStorage or a database.

Comment: thanks for the info @urbz

Comment: @MaKobi, thanks, to be more specific would store in database effect speed if data get bigger?

Answer (score 0):

One simple fast solution with localStorage. You can use other storages or databases.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var messages = localStorage.getItem('msg');
  if (messages) {
    messages.split(';').forEach(function(msg) {
      $('#messageArea').append('<div>' + msg + '</div>');
    });
  }
});

socket.on('message', function(data) {
  var messages = localStorage.getItem('msg') || '';
  if (messages) {
    messages += ';';
  }
  messages += data;
  localStorage.setItem('msg', messages);
  $('#messageArea').append('<div>' + data + '</div>');
});
```

With this answer, you might not use ';' in the message. It's just an **example** to show you that you have to save message data somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: The error shows - .forEach is not a function, have try .each already. Any idea? @ZeroCho

Comment: @Blair Which browser do you use? forEach is a native method of Array of ES5. `messages.split(';')` returns Array and you can use forEach. However, if your browser is IE8 or under, they don't support ES5, which cause error.

Comment: I try Chorme and Firefox, like the code above still get the same error "Uncaught TypeError: messages.split is not a function"  @ZeroCho

Comment: @Blair Can you tell me the result of console.log of messages? messages should be in type of string in order to use split method.

Comment: I try to save string to an array but still not working tho

Comment: I can find the key-value pair in devtool, but still when refresh the page content gone.

Comment: Thank you it works now, the main issue is the messages append on webpage are gone when I hit refresh